# Hyper-V Cmdlet for networking VMQ

Tags: networking, powershell, hyper-v, network-adapter

When I run this:

```
Set-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $vmName -Name "Network Adapter" -VMQ
```

I get this:

```
Set-VMNetworkAdapter : Missing an argument for parameter 'VmqWeight'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.UInt32]' and
try again.
At line:1 char:62
+ Set-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $vmName -Name "Network Adapter" -VMQ
+                                                              ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-VMNetworkAdapter], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.SetVMNetworkAdapter
```

So I try to add the `VmqWeight`:

```
Set-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $vmName -Name "Network Adapter" -VMQ -VmqWeight 30
```

and I get this:

```
Set-VMNetworkAdapter : Missing an argument for parameter 'VmqWeight'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.UInt32]' and
try again.
At line:1 char:62
+ ... VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $vmName -Name "Network Adapter" -VMQ -VmqWei ...
+                                                              ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-VMNetworkAdapter], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.SetVMNetworkAdapter
```

I looked up `-VmqWeight` and it is supposed to have a value between -100 and 100.

What is the correct syntax to set these options on my VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PowerShell logic, `-VMQ` is expanded to `-VmqWeight`. This argument requires a parameter, which you do not give. Your command must read:

```
Set-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $vmName -Name "Network Adapter" -VMQ 30
```

(But you really should use the full parameter name anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for
[Set-VMNetworkAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmnetworkadapter?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
does not mention a parameter named `VMQ`, only `VmqWeight`
is listed.

Try the command without `--VMQ`.

Comment: Ah, thanks very much. I saw various things online that confused me on this. This works.